# Sharepoint 2013 With IE 11 - 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: 2013, internet-explorer, authorization

I have authentication problem when used IE to access my SharePoint site. When I enter the address of the site, I don't receive any prompt to enter username and password and I get the error message "401 UNAUTHORIZED". I have no such problem when using Firefox or Chrome. I searched about this problem and a solution was changing authentication type in IIS from "Windows Authentication" to "Basic Authentication". This solution worked for me, but Basic Authentication is not secure and I don't want to use it. Is there any solution else to solve this problem?

Comment: did you check for any proxy setting issues in the IE ?

Comment: Yes, I did. There isn't proxy set.